# Google Gmail API filter by Label not working properly in case CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS

Tags: api, filter, gmail, label, promotions

The Google Gmail API filter by Label doesn't seem to work properly in case CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS.

When I used the query string **-label:INBOX**, the results did not list messages labeled INBOX. It is right.

BUT, I wanted to NOT list messages labeled CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS so I used the query string **-label:CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS**. BUT, the results are STILL listed messages labeled CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS.

Any experience with this? Is this a bug of Google Gmail API?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question include [example].  Describe your issue in detail include any links to docs and error messages that may be needed to fully explain your issue.   If we cant recreate it with what you are giving us its hard to help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.